# Emphasis is put on relation of A and B, instead of/on

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, translation

Having the following sentence, I'm not sure how to use prepositions after 'instead':

> The emphasis is put on the relation between A and B, instead of on A
>   and B themselves.

Is "instead of on" correct? Also not sure about the usage of "themselves here".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"instead of on" is correct, but it's not very clear. The simplest way to use a preposition is (preposition) + (object), and the further you get from that formula, the harder your reader has to work to figure out what you mean.

A clearer phrasing might be:
'This emphasizes the relationship between A and B, without focusing on A and B themselves.'

Answer (score -1):

I would rather say," The emphasis is on the relation between A and B, not on A and B themselves."